# 'string' does not contain a definition for 'todatetime'

Tags: c#, function, datetime

I am running into the error `'string' does not contain a definition for 'ToDateTime'` during the part of my code that is making sure the current date value is populated. Here are the pieces of code:

```
public class LegalTransactionRec
{
    public string AccountNumber { get; set; }
    public string CostAmount { get; set; }
    public string SSN { get; set; }
    public int BatchID { get; set; }
    public Attorney Attorney { get; set; }
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int TransactionCode { get; set; }
}
```

Its going down right here:

```
TransactionDate = Form1.CheckDate(xlRange.Cells[i, 2].Value2.ToDateTime())
```

Here is the function that is checking to make sure the field is populated:

```
public static DateTime CheckDate(DateTime tranDate)
{
    DateTime date;
    if (tranDate == null)
    {
        throw new System.ArgumentException("Value cannot be null", "original");
    }
    else
    {
        date = tranDate;
    }
    return date;
}
```

EDIT: Code for xlRange:

```
        try
        {

            //workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(txtbxFilename.Text);                      View above comment
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet worksheet = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range xlRange = worksheet.UsedRange;

            int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
            int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

            for (int i = 1; i <= rowCount; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
                {
                    lstTran.Add(new LegalTransactionRec()
                    {
                        AccountNumber = Form1.CleanString(xlRange.Cells[i, 1].Value2.ToString()),
                        CostAmount = Form1.TryToParse(Form1.CleanAmount(xlRange.Cells[i, 3].Value2.ToString())),
                        SSN = Form1.CleanString(xlRange.Cells[i, 6].Value2.ToString()),
                        TransactionDate = Form1.CheckDate(xlRange.Cells[i, 2].Value2.ToDateTime()),
                        Description = xlRange.Cells[i, 8].Value2.ToString(),
                        TransactionCode = xlRange.Cells[i, 4].Value2.ToInt() //Work on the CheckNull function later
                    });
                }
            }

        }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is `xlRange.Cells[i, 2].Value2`?

Comment: Well, for one, a DateTime value can never ever be null. Still, the error message you're getting is strange, is that what it actually says? Or does it say it doesn't contain a definition for `ToDateTime`?

Comment: I don't see the definition for xlRange anywhere, can you post the code for xlRange?

Comment: Wondering if it should read "...(xlRange.Cells[i, 2].Value).ToDateTime();"

Comment: @KevinJ What's the difference?

Comment: @dvnrrs Its part of a for loop that is adding values to a List.

Comment: I think @KevinJ is pointing out that `Value2` is odd.  `Value` seems more appropriate.

Comment: @Luaan You are correct, it is for ToDateTime. It used to just be DateTime before I made a change.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your `CheckDate` method is worthless.  Dates cant be null, they can have a value of Jan 1 0001 or some such.

Comment: @paqogomez Reason for the check is the List is being populated with values from an excel spreadsheet. I thought it would be wise to check the column in which I am getting the Date from.

Comment: @paqogomez Value2 is correct, read this this on [Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range_members.aspx)

Comment: @JohnOdom: Nope, "The only difference between this property and the Value property is that the Value2 property doesn’t use the Currency and Date data types."

Comment: @JohnOdom Wow!  Never knew that!  Never seen that!  Thanks!

Comment: @Luaan I forgot to read that part, just posting to show that Value2 is a valid property. If it doesn't use the Date data type then OP should use Value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, Value2 contains a string, plain an simple. You want to use something like this:

```
static DateTime ConvertToDateTime(object obj)
{
  if (obj == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException();

  return (DateTime)obj;
}
```

And then just call

```
ConvertToDateTime(xlRange.Cells[i, 2].Value);
```

to get the date time.

Or, if `Value` still returns a string, you can do

```
static DateTime ConvertToDateTime(string str)
{
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(str))
    throw new ArgumentNullException();

  return DateTime.Parse(str);
}
```

You may have to call it like this:

```
ConvertToDateTime(xlRange.Cells[i, 2].Value as string);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, with these changes Im getting `The string was not recognized as a valid DateTime. There is an unknown word starting at index 0`.  For reference this is what the date looks like in the excel spreadsheet `1/20/2014`. I'll look into this.

Comment: Think I might have made progress, after removing the header (silly move on my part) it looks like this change worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2405778 `DateTime.TryParse` might handle this better than just a cast to a DateTime.